# IF statement that is between two values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Hi im trying to make an IF statement that if data is input in a certain column that isnt between 0 and 100 then it comes up as an error and if it is then it comes up as ok

I want it so that if data in the E column is not between 0 and 100 then the cell below data checking comes up as error
and if the data in the E column is between 0 and 100 then the cell below data checking comes up as error

```
E

30

40

41

32

21

56

20

data checking

ok
```

all help is much appreciated

Comment: Are those values entered or produced by a formula? You can completely prevent them from being outside the 0-100 range by using Data Validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say your values are in E4:E17

You can count the number of values greater than 100, and the number of values less than zero and add them together.  If the result is greater than zero, you have an error.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E4:E17,">100")+COUNTIF(E4:E17,"<0") > 0,"error","ok")
```